# Script to pull out info out of very large drives

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I need a script that can gather folders/files information from large drives (600GB to 1TB). The info that I will need are:

- Full name/path of the file
- File Size
- Date Created
- Date Modified
- Date last accessed.

So far I have the code below:

```
dir 'e:\' -recurse | 
     select FullName,Length,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,LastAccessTime | 
     Export-CSV e:\test\testit.csv -notype
```

Would it be possible to get the script adapted so as it can search on ‘If modified date is equal to ‘xxx’ days or older, then output data to csv..

The xxx would be the figure – i.e 365 for 1 year or more old.. or xxx would be the figure – i.e 730 for 2 years or more old..

Also would it be possible to modify the headers for the columns that it outputs on CSV file?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of question, you might use

```
# fixed date
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ | ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt [datetime]'2009-02-23' }
# variable depending on current date; it returns only items that are older than 365 days
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ | ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-365) }
```

As for modifying the headers.. I is possible to select items with different names but with the same content (~rename the properties):

```
Select-Object @{Name='ItemName'; Expression={$_.FullName } }, 
        @{Name='Write'; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime } }, 
        @{Name='Access'; Expression={$_.LastAccessTime } }
```

Note that there is a script block where you can do whatever you want. You can e.g. format the dates `{$_.LastAccessTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') }`

---

If I put it together (there are only 3 properties 'renamed')

```
Get-ChildItem e:\ -rec | 
    ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-365) } |
    Select-Object @{Name='ItemName'; Expression={$_.FullName } }, 
        @{Name='Write'; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime } }, 
        @{Name='Access'; Expression={$_.LastAccessTime } } |
    Export-Csv e:\test\testit.csv -notype
```

Comment: Thanks mate! that worked perfect :)

now another thing is that I have some documents which are encrypted, is there a way that it could either skip those documents or actually go through them as well?

Thanks

Comment: bascially at work 'my documents' folder is encrypted so that the files can only be accessed by myself or an administrator.

Comment: Hm, I don't know now. Try to ask a new question with more info and maybe with more information I'll find some answer or somebody else.

Comment: sorry again, another quick issue, if the file name/path is longer than 248 characters it gives an error, is there any way to prevent it from that?

Thanks

Comment: Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. the fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters and the directory must be less than 248 characters

Comment: From what I know you can't really work around that one, all the System.IO .Net classes respect the traditional MAX_PATH value
(which is 260 chars). For some info check http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/filesystem-paths-how-long-is-too-long.html